# Tasks linger in celery amqp when publisher is terminated

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am using `Celery` with a `RabbitMQ` server. I have a publisher, which could potentially be terminated by a `SIGKILL` and since this signal cannot be watched, I cannot revoke the tasks. What would be a common approach to revoke the tasks where the publisher is not alive anymore?

I experimented with an interval on the worker side, but the publisher is obviously not registered as a worker, so I don't know how I can detect a timeout

Comment: Highly unusual use-case... Let us know how you solved it. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, yes, it invalidates the task. A publisher sends several tasks to consumers where they get processed. The result of it will then be further processed. If the publisher dies, the post process doesn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution, which works in my case, is to add the next task only if the current processed ones are finished. In this case the queue doesn't fill up.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing built-in to celery to monitor the producer / publisher status -- only the worker / consumer status.  There are other alternatives that you can consider, for example by using a redis expiring key that has to be updated periodically by the publisher that can serve as a proxy for whether a publisher is alive.  And then in the task checking to see if the flag for a publisher still exists within redis, and if it doesn't the task returns doing nothing.

Comment: To expand on this, not only does celery not monitor anything about the publisher, RabbitMQ is also a queuing system that does not allow for arbitrary message access so there is no way to get the message out of the queue without draining the queue up until that message

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure what you want is not possible with Celery, so I suggest you to shift your logic around and redesign everything to be part of a [Celery workflow](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html) (or several Celery canvases depends on the actual use-case). My experience with Celery is that you can build literally any workflow you can imagine with those [Celery primitives](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives) and/or custom Celery signatures.